# ¿Generar un id diferente x veces para un botón en Vue dentro de una lista en html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo una lista `<ul>` con una cantidad de `<li>` según la cantidad de items que existen el array `items` Los items los añade el usuario al pulsar un botón

```
<li v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">{{ i }}
       <b-button id="" @click="deleteItem" variant="outline-dark">Borrar item</b-button>
    </li>

items: [
    "en la lista", "habrá", "tres <li>"
  ]
```

Pero también quiero añadir a cada `<li>` un botón que se encargue de borrar ese item en concreto. Cómo no se que item realmente va a borrar el usuario, pienso ponerle un id diferente a cada botón "Borrar" , pero necesitaría que este id se pusiese dinámicamente porque tampoco se cuantos items va a ñadir el usuario, claro.

¿Como hacer esto?

Mi plan es que luego en la función `deleteItem` colocaría el id como argumento y dependiendo de cual se borraría el item en la posición x del array `items`:

```js
deleteItem: function (id){
    let stringtoDelete = this.items[id-1]
    this.items.filter(v => v !== stringtoDelete)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacerlo utilizando una función  que le envié como parámetro el índex del elemento, el código se vería así.

```
<li v-for="i in items" :key="i.id">{{ i }}
   <b-button id="" @click="deleteItem(i)" variant="outline-dark">Borrar item</b-button>
</li>
```

y la función así

```
deleteItem: function (i){
let stringtoDelete = this.items[i]
this.items.filter(v => v !== stringtoDelete)}
```

Si aún así lo prefieres hacer con la id sería lo mismo

Comment: No me funciona. He abierto las devtools y me sale el siguiente error:  Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" Se te ocurre alguna idea de por qué podría ser?